# Is it common to use "perverted" (as in a pervert) as an adjective?

Tags: word-usage

Example:

> Just one room for the two of us? Aha! You did have a perverted plan
>   after all!

So, in this case "perverted" is the adjective form of "pervert":

> **pervert** 
>  nounˈpəːvəːt/1.a person whose sexual behaviour is regarded as
>   abnormal and unacceptable.

Source: [Google](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=pervert&oq=pervert&gs_l=serp.3..0i67j0j0i67l2j0l6.40857.43457.0.43847.9.7.2.0.0.0.201.910.0j5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.8.925.zkdpRHLG63Y).

But then I checked on Google Books, and realized that there's not only one result for my phrase, but the phrase has a different meaning:

> "She and her husband had a perverted plan to spread cannibalism to
>   others."

Source: [Google Books](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22%20had%20a%20perverted%20plan%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=l_STVcquCIbe8AW3gIHYDA&ved=0CA4Q_AUoAQ&biw=1280&bih=938).

Is my usage uncommon? If so, what's a better option?

Comment: This depends mainly on context. In the context of the first sentence I would certainly read perverted the way you defined it lower. One possible similar word that might avoid ambiguity though is "kinky". The merriam-webster has one of the definitions of "kinky" as "  relating to, having, or appealing to unconventional tastes especially in sex; also :  sexually deviant", and as far I can tell it has if anything a more positive bias.

Comment: Your first example strikes me as slightly odd. Many people (particularly, *women*) might think that some other people (often *men*) are excessively "pushy" in trying to set up situations where they get to have sex. But whereas booking yourself and your holiday/travelling companion into a single hotel room might be described as overly presumptive (or optimistic! :), I'd hardly say that's ***perverted*** behaviour. To many people, in many situations, it's just par for the course. (Asking Room Service to bring you whips and chains is a different matter, obviously! )

Comment: "Pervert" is one of a group of English words (like "record," "compact," and "contract") that is pronounced as a trochee when used a noun and as an iamb when used as a verb. As a noun, it can conceivably be pressed into service as an adjective, but using the past participle of the verb form is a more usual choice.

Comment: @fumblefingers I'm guessing that whether this is considered perverted depends a lot on both any extra context and the society/culture of the actors.

Comment: @DRF: Of course. But as an *example*, it does seem to stretch the meaning of *perverted* for most likely contexts - where I think it would be more natural for most people to say *...you had a **game** plan* (that plan being to have "normal" sex with the speaker, probably nothing particularly kinky).

Comment: @fumblefingers true. Probably the best result would be if the op could clarify what led him to choose perverted in the first place.

Comment: @DRF: Again - of course. That's why I've closevoted as "Primarily Opinion-based". I'm not sure you and I actually have *different* opinions about this one, but if we don't know exactly what OP himself wishes to imply (about the plan), we don't even know which of our (possibly multiple) opinions to promote.

Comment: You don't seem to have noticed that _perverted_ is not simply the adjectival form of _pervert_. They have very different connotations. A pervert is nearly always someone you'd categorise as a sexual deviant in some way. If something is _perverted_, it much more commonly means that it is “of an abnormal, unnatural kind; wicked, distorted, cruel” (ODO). The adjective can also be used in the sense relating to the noun, but only when context makes it clear that that is what's meant. Your example makes it sound like X’s plan is to murder and eat Y, not just share a bed with them.

Comment: "Perverted" has a range of meanings.

Comment: _pervert_ is both a noun (referring to the sexual deviant) and a verb (meaning to distort). _perverted_ as an adjective comes from the verb.

Comment: I'd say: "Aha! So you planned all this from the beginning!" But more context is needed. Is the speaker secretly pleased, or highly irritated and offended by the arrangement. Has the hotel booker (presumably a man) been trying to woo her? Is the speaker a prude, or is she slightly mocking the man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an American English speaker's point of view, I would have phrased your second sentence as, "She and her husband had a **perverse** plan to spread cannibalism to others."

To use perverted in a non-sexual sense but in a common comparative sentence, consider the following sentence.

"The local culture of sharing burdens among the village was perverted by the power and influence of currency."

Comment: The second phrase is a sample quoted from Google Books. The OP is asking whether his first suggestion is appropriate.